# How to generate succesive dates? (add N days to date)

Tags: windows, parsing, batch-file

I am writing a simple batch script that allows the user to input a beginning date and an end date and it transfers files with the date in the name. It takes in the year month day like so '20220215'. For example, the user types '20211110' and then '20211215' it grabs the files from November 11th, 2021 to December 15th, 2021. I am trying to grab the day and month from the input string but the problem is the values '08' and '09' give the script trouble because of hex values and such. So I do cases for the file day which works fine because it is at the end of the string. The issue is the month. Here is the code:

```
REM Works fine
IF !temp_var:~6! == 08 (
    SET /A file_day = 8
) ELSE IF !temp_var:~6! == 09 (
    SET /A file_day = 9
) ELSE (
    SET /A file_day = !temp_var:~6!
)

REM Crashes script
IF !temp_var:~4, -2! == 08 (
    SET /A file_month = 8
) ELSE IF !temp_var:~4, -2! == 09 (
    SET /A file_month = 9
) ELSE (
    SET /A file_month = !temp_var:~4, -2!
```

The error I recieve when I run the script is

```
-2 was unexpected at this time.
```

Which I found is simply at the first IF statement at the month block. But everytime I search up how to grab digits from a variable, it uses the %var:~#:#% format.

I have comtemplated switching to another language or way to do this but I figured the task I am trying to automate was simple and could be achieved with putting together a batch to run a few commands haha.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: It's `!temp_var:~4,-2!`, not `!temp_var:~4, -2!`. No spaces. Also, remove the spaces from around _all_ of the equals signs and put quotes around the things that are being compared. `IF "!temp_var:~4,-2!"=="08" SET /A file_month=8`, etc.

Comment: I don't understand what is the purpose to individually take the year-month-day from the user input. You can directly compare a date string vs the YYYYMMDD string given as input... Perhaps this is a X-Y problem?

Comment: Anyway, this is a very simple way to solve your problem: `set /A "file_month=1!temp_var:~4,-2!-100, file_day=1!temp_var:~6!-100"`

Comment: @Aacini, I need to iterate from first date to second date. I need to count up to day 30 and then switch to the next month, and then count to 12 for months and switch to year, etc. I'm downloading files that have the date in the name

Comment: @r_mchugh: In such a case, I changed the question title to "How to generate succesive dates? (add 1 day to date)" so I can post the answer below...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This program generate a series of succesive dates:

```
@echo off
setlocal

echo      Date format: YYYYMMDD
set /P "startDate=Enter start date: "
set /P "endDate=Enter end date:   "
echo/
echo %startDate%

set /A "YYYY=%startDate:~0,4%, m=1%startDate:~4,2%-100, d=1%startDate:~6%-100"
:nextDate
set /A "d+=1, nextMon=!(d-(31+((m+m/8)&1)-!(m-2)*(2-!(YYYY%%4)))), d=d*!nextMon+nextMon, m+=nextMon, nextYear=!(m-13), m=m*!nextYear+nextYear, YYYY+=nextYear, MM=100+m, DD=100+d"
set "nextDate=%YYYY%%MM:~1%%DD:~1%
echo %nextDate%
if %nextDate% neq %endDate% goto nextDate
```

This is a description of the method used:

- `d+=1` is the next day.
- `30+((m+m/8)&1)-!(m-2)*(2-!(YYYY%%4))` is the number of days per month accordingly to:

1=31, 2=28 or 29, 3=31, 4=30, 5=31, 6=30, 7=31, 8=31, 9=30, 10=31, 11=30 and 12=31.

That is, get a 30 + 1 for odd months from 1 to 7 (30+0 otherwise), and switch to 30 + 1 for even months after 7 (30+0 otherwise), and an additional adjustment (this result -2 or -1) for February. To get such a result, we used these parts:

`(m+m/8)` is M for M<8 and M+1 otherwise. `((m+m/8)&1)` is the 1 or 0 that we add to 30 in months <> 2.

`(m-2)` is 0 for M==2 and <>0 otherwise, so `!(m-2)` is 1 for M==2 and 0 otherwise, and `!(m-2)*2` is the 2 we subtract from 30 to give 28 when M==2. `YYYY%%4` is 0 when the year is divisible by 4 and <>0 otherwise, so `!(YYYY%%4)` is an adjustment of 1 (that we rest from the 2 that gives 28) when the year is leap (so in leap years February gives 29).

Finally, we assemble all these parts and get: `30+((m+m/8)&1)-!(m-2)*(2-!(YYYY%%4))` that is the number of DaysPerMonth for all months and all years. Changing `30` by `31` gives the number of DaysPerMonthPlusOne.

Technicall note: this formula does not comply with the rule that a year is *not* a leap year when it is divisible by 400 (like 2000), so the method will fail in year 2400. To fix this point, we need to cancel the adjustment of 1 when the year be divisible by 400, that is: `31+((m+m/8)&1)-!(m-2)*(2-!(YYYY%%4)+!(YYYY%%400))`

- `d-(DaysPerMonthPlusOne)` is 0 when the next day have exceeded the number of days in the month, so `nextMon=!(d-(DaysPerMonthPlusOne))` is 1 when the month have changed, and 0 otherwise.
- `d=d*!nextMon+nextMon` is the same D value when the month have not changed, and 1 (the value of nextMon) otherwise.
- `m+=nextMon` increments M when the month have changed.
- `m-13` is 0 when M have exceeded the year, so `nextYear=!(m-13)` is 1 when the year have changed (and 0 otherwise).
- `m=m*!nextYear+nextYear` is the same M value when the year have not changed, and 1 (the value of nextYear) otherwise.
- `YYYY+=nextYear` increments YYYY when the year have changed.
- Finally `MM=100+m, DD=100+d` are variables with 3 digits (like 103 when m is 3) that are used to show the month and day with two digits each.

Reference: I developed this method by myself...  **;)**

**EDIT 2022/03/23**: *Modification to add several days added*

I modified this program in order to add *several* (more than one) days. The method works correctly as long as the increment of days does not jump to more than one month forward. Although the method could be easily modified in order to work with any number of days, the modification can not be achieved in a single arithmetic expression...

```
@echo off
setlocal

echo      Date format: YYYYMMDD
set /P "startDate=Enter start date: "
set /P "endDate=Enter end date:   "
set /P "numDays=Enter days increment: "
echo/
echo %startDate%

set /A "YYYY=%startDate:~0,4%, m=1%startDate:~4,2%-100, d=1%startDate:~6%-100"
:nextDate
set /A "d+=numDays, DPM=30+((m+m/8)&1)-!(m-2)*(2-!(YYYY%%4)), nextMon=((d-1-DPM)>>31)+1, d-=nextMon*DPM, m+=nextMon, nextYear=!(m-13), m=m*!nextYear+nextYear, YYYY+=nextYear, MM=100+m, DD=100+d"
set "nextDate=%YYYY%%MM:~1%%DD:~1%
echo %nextDate%
if %nextDate% lss %endDate% goto nextDate
```

These are the details that changed in the new method:

- `(d-1-DPM)` is *negative* when the day is less or equal DaysPerMonth and 0 or positive otherwise, so `((d-1-DPM)>>31)` (such result Shift right 31 bits) is -1 when day is in the same month and 0 otherwise, so `nextMon=((d-1-DPM)>>31)+1` is 1 when the month have changed, and 0 otherwise.
- `d-=nextMon*DPM` subtract the number of days of current month when the day belongs to next month.